# Populate each row of a tableView according to a section

Tags: ios, objective-c, tableview

I have a tableView witch have sections and variable number of rows, according to external data.

For populate cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I have an array containing other array like this:

```
(
    (
    "segunda-feira, 28 de janeiro 2013",
    1978,
    "Luana de Lima ",
    "09:00"
),
    (
    "s\U00e1bado, 26 de janeiro 2013",
    1979,
    "Marcus Vinicius Gimenes",
    "12:00"
),
    (
    "s\U00e1bado, 26 de janeiro 2013",
    1979,
    "Joana dark",
    "12:30"
),
    (
    "s\U00e1bado, 26 de janeiro 2013",
    1978,
    "Joana dark",
    "09:00"
),
    (
    "ter\U00e7a-feira, 29 de janeiro 2013",
    1978,
    "Joana dark",
    "09:00"
),
    (
    "domingo, 27 de janeiro 2013",
    1978,
    "Marcus Vinicius Gimenes",
    "09:00"
)
)
```

Where the `objectAtIndex:0` of each array is equal of a section title and has to be placed in that section.

My code is like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell =nil;
    static NSString *identifier = @"ScheduleCell";
    ScheduleCell *cell = (ScheduleCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ScheduleCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    if([[self tableView:tableView titleForHeaderInSection:indexPath.section] isEqualToString:    [[self.appointmentsFormatted objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:0]])
    {
        cell.nome.text = [[self.appointmentsFormatted objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:2];
        cell.horario.text = [[self.appointmentsFormatted objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:3];               
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Question is how to right populate the rows? I'm getting bad function that if a value in an array is used, then a equal value of that or other array just doesn't shows up in cell.

Comment: check my answe, It may resolved your crash.

Comment: Why you using your dataSource structure like this? You can keep separate array for each section before populating tableView.

Comment: You have quite bad data. I can't come up wit ha straightforward solution to populate table cells from that stuff. I suggest to somewhat parse them again to make them more developer-friendly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your dataSource structure, it is difficult to populate the tableView directly like this. Re-design your dataSource structure if you can. If it is returned from  any service or like that change the structure before populating tableView.

```
- (NSMutableArray *)createDataSource:(NSArray *)inputArray
{
  NSMutableArray *outputArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  NSMutableArray *titleArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

  for (NSArray *rowArray in inputArray) {
    if (![titleArray containsObject:[rowArray objectAtIndex:0]]) {
        [titleArray addObject:[rowArray objectAtIndex:0]];
    }
  }

  for (NSString *title in titleArray) {
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
        return [[evaluatedObject objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:title];
    }];
    NSArray *sectionArray = [inputArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    [outputArray addObject:sectionArray];
  }

  return outputArray;
}
```

After that you can directly use your dataSource in `- (UITableViewCell*) tableView:(UITableView*) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*) indexPath` method,

```
- (UITableViewCell*) tableView:(UITableView*) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*) indexPath
{
  // I am using outputArray for your self.appointmentsFormatted which is generated from the method

  cell.nome.text = [[[outputArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:2];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, using your method passing my array as argument, how can i access the in cellForRowAIndexPath?
Like: cell.nome.text = @"string inside arrays"

Comment: @ArthurMastropietro You can access that string inside array. I have updated the code. Try that..

Comment: Nice, but when i try to use that syntax:
    cell.nome.text = [[[self.appointmentsFormatted objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:2];
it gives me an error: Expected ']'

Comment: @ArthurMastropietro Sorry.. One `objectAtIndex` was missing.. I have corrected that.. Try now..

Comment: I tried, but i got an array out of bounds for objectAtIndex.indexPath.row: "index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]". I think the data returning from method has an array with 1 index (0). Would be it?

Comment: Nice! i figured out why it was not working, because the [objectAtIndexPath:indexPath.section] ObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] was not matching the dataSource indexes, cause that datasource was not sorted as the sections are. When i remove sections order everything goes right. Is there a way to sort sections by their titles dinamicaly instead sorting the array that feeds sections titles?
Besides it, your code is great! Appreciate your help!